# How to conditionally disable a windows push button?

Tags: winforms, button

I'm developing a simple application to allow the user to solve the towers of Hanoi puzzle. 
I need to be able to conditionally disable some buttons on the interface.
(i.e if a particular move is against the rules, the button for that move must be disable).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can button disable on move event and if move is against the rules, set `button.Enabled = false`

Or you can simply ignore the button action on button click event if move is against the rules.

### Edit

You may have already events to move the puzzle, on those events you can validate the rules.

for example, in your your event call method which enable, disable buttons based on rules

```
private void CheckState()
{
    if(!CheckRuleOne())
    {
      button1.Enabled = false;
    }
   // more rules and validations ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should do some check after a move, and see if which buttons are allowed or not, and a simple `button.Enabled = false` should disable your button

Comment: I tried that.. but I don't know how to find the button objects. (all the buttons were generated by visual studio)

Comment: @mahela007 Look on the designer - highlight the button you want, and it'll tell you the name in the properties window. You _really_ should be naming them something sensible so you can find them later anyway.

Comment: I had named them properly.. I didn't know how to access the buttons when writing the code for the event handlers. (C++ and winForms newbie.. hehe) 
but I found them now.. thanks.